# Printing 2d array in javascript

Tags: javascript

[image: rail]

Like the picture above, how would it be possible to create four separate lines of text, given the word `defendtheeastwallofthecastle` while using Javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by row number of 4 in javascript??

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: Have you tried to do something?

Comment: Hint: you can use loops and modulo (`%`) operation.

Comment: You're not coming to stackoverflow to do your computer science homework are you? Stuff like this is supposed to be fun!

Answer (score 2):

### Math solution

Take a closer look at your output:

```
a.....g.....m.....s.
.b...f.h...l.n...r.t
..c.e...i.k...o.q...
...d.....j.....p....
```

Note that it can be splitted into similiar repeating blocks:

```
a.....    g.....    m.....    s.
.b...f    .h...l    .n...r    .t
..c.e.    ..i.k.    ..o.q.    ..
...d..    ...j..    ...p..    ..
```

The length of this blocks is calculable: every row, except for the first one and the last one, has 2 letters. The total length will be: `rows * 2 - 2`. Let's call it `blockLength`. By the way, `x * 2 - 2` is always even - it is important.

Now, you can see that in every block the letters are "sinking" in the left half, and arising in the second one. So, if you make some observations and analysis, you will understand that for `blockLength == 6` you need to output letters at i:

```
 row  |  i % blockLength
----------------------------
  0   |         0
  1   |  1, blockLength - 1
  2   |  2, blockLength - 2
  3   |         3
```

After `i` exceeds `blockLength`, it will repeat again and again, until the end of the string. This regularity can be easily converted to a JavaScript loop, if you know its basics.

### Lazy solution

Within a loop set values in zig-zag order:

```
var str = 'abcdefghijklmopqrst';
var rows = 4, letterRows = [], currentRow = 0, direction = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
{
    letterRows.push(currentRow);
    currentRow += direction;

    if ((direction === 1 && currentRow == rows - 1) // bottom limit
     || (direction === -1 && currentRow == 0)) // top limit 
    {
       direction = direction * -1; // invert direction                                 
    }
}
```

Then, within nested loops simply output your letters according to `letterRows`:

```
for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        output(letterRows[i] == row ? str[i] : '.'); // output is any possible output in your case
    }
    output('\n');
}
```

Comment: +1 for your explanation, but the "direction" business seems messy to me. Here's an alternative (I'd write my own answer but I'm too lazy to write up the explanation since I'm typing this on my phone...): https://jsfiddle.net/jrunning/rct22gd4/